# Is that possible to control the polling rate of a mouse in USB host mode?

Tags: usb, stm32cubeide

I'm using an STM32F4 device and CubeIDE SW to interface with a mouse as a host with an HID. I use the USBH_HID_EventCallback function to trigger mouse readings.

Can I change the mouse's polling rate so that it will be triggering faster?

The current polling rate (per USBH_HID_GetPollInterval function) is 10ms. In the mouse's data sheet, it states it can reach 1kHz polling rate.

Thanks